# When does MainApplication get killed and what happens if after that a static function from it is called?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

When does MainApplication get killed in Android? Is it always present, even after 1 month after user doesn't open the app? What happens if it's killed, and I call a static method from it, e.g. `MainApplication.doSomeWork()` - will in this case first be recreated?

Comment: if the application gets killed, you won;t be able to call any method, as **it is already killed**

Comment: Then how do I need to implement a function only **once**, which gets required data from internet and saves it to DB, which can be called from any point in code (Activity, BroadcastReceiver, Service, etc..) ?

Comment: when the application gets killed, you are unable to execute any code anymore. Neither from Activity. not BroadcastReceiver, Service, etc.  Application is killed without any notification, so it will just immediately stop executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Android can decide the kill application because of memory management and all static variables gone. When you reopen app its start from where it was. Because android saves fragment state if you added to back stack. You can put your lightweight data in bundle and store it when Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) method called and get it later in Fragment.onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) method. If you have to store large data, you should use a database . (Sql, Realm, Objectbox, etc). But all static variables will get lost.